# How can I positionize table in PDF using ReportLab?

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I am intresting to create report in PDF format. My report supposed to have some title at the top of PDF and table below of the title. How can I positionize table in exact place in my PDF list?

Now my table is created on top of the title.
You can see my code below:

Sorry if my question looks silly, I just start use ReportLab recently.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
class Ui_WinTable(object):
    def title(self,canvas,doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('Courier-Bold', 16)
        canvas.drawString(200, 800, 'Oil Consumption Report')
        canvas.drawImage('s7logoforreport.bmp', 450, 780)
        canvas.setFont('Courier', 14)
        canvas.drawString(240, 780, 'TSN: ' + self.comboBox_TSN.currentText())
        canvas.drawString(240, 740, 'Engine 1 ' + self.comboBox_Eng.currentText())
    def createPDF(self):
        elements = []
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate('example.pdf', pagesize=A4)
        data = [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
                ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
                ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
                ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]
        t1 = Table(data, 20, 20)
        elements.append(t1)
        doc.build(elements,onFirstPage=self.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the margins to create the space for the title in the doc. Like this:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file,pagesize=A4,rightMargin=3*cm,leftMargin=3*cm,topMargin=4*cm,bottomMargin=3*cm)
doc.build(Story, onFirstPage=cabeceraPortada, onLaterPages=cabecera)
```